# Recording a screencast of an Android app using the emulator

Tags: android, emulation

Unlike the iPhone simulator, the Android emulator doesn't look like an Android device.

If you have to create a screencast or promotional video of your Android application, the default skin of the emulator is no good.

Is there any way to configure the emulator to look like an Android device? If you have dealt with this already, what other things do you recommend taking into account to record an emulator screencast?

Not a programming question per se, but an useful question for Android developers.

Comment: Whatever happened to the salmon-esque looking skin?

Comment: We actually made a couple of videos with that skin. There's a place in marketing hell for us for doing this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use an Emulator skin, for example like found [here](http://www.android.encke.net/) for several devices.

Comment: For those looking for something more recent: http://blog.mathiaslin.com/nexus-one-emulator-skin-updated

Comment: Nice link, thanks for posting. BTW using this skin it takes all my screen, so I can't see the top and bottom parts of the Nexus One. Is there a way to make it smaller?

Comment: Set the scale parameter to something lower than 1.

Comment: You can find skins for Nexus S and Nexus One including a reflection overlay (great for screencasts) and a tutorial how to use the options for -scale and -onion at http://HeikoBehrens.net/2011/03/15/android-skins/